# A better way to split apply and combine in R using sp::merge() as function

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sp

I have a dataframe with 500 observations for each of 3106 US counties. I would like to merge that dataframe with a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

I have tried a few approaches. I have found that if I filter the data by a variable `iter_id` I can use `sp::merge()` to merge the datasets. I presume that I can then `rbind` them back together. `sp::merge()` does not allow a right or full join and the spatial data needs to be in the left position. So a many to one will not work. The really nasty way I have tried is: 
(I am not sure how to represent the dataframe with the variables of interest here)

```
library(choroplethr)
data(continental_us_states)
us <- tigris::counties(continental_us_states)

gm_y_corr <- tribble(~GEOID,~iter_id,~neat_variable,
01001,1,"value_1",
01003,1,"value_2",
...
01001,2,"value_3",
01003,2,"value_4",
...
01001,500,"value_5",
01003,500,"value_6")

filtered <- gm_y_corr %>%
  filter(iter_id ==1)

us.gm <- sp::merge(us, filtered ,by='GEOID')

for (j in 2:500) {
tmp2 <- gm_y_corr %>%
  filter(iter_id == j)
tmp3 <- sp::merge(us, tmp2,by='GEOID')
us.gm <- rbind(us.gm,tmp3)
}
```

I know there must be a better way. I have tried `group_by`. But multple matches are found. So I must not be understanding the `group_by`.

```
> geo_dat <- gm_y_corr %>%
+   group_by(iter_id)%>%
+   sp::merge(us, .,by='GEOID')
Error in .local(x, y, ...) : non-unique matches detected
```

I would like to merge the spatial data with the interesting data.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use the splitting functionality of base R in `split` or the more recent `dplyr::group_split`. This will separate your data frame according to your splitting variable and you can `lapply` or `purrr::map` a function such as `merge` to it and then `dplyr::bind_rows` to collapse the returned list back to a `dataframe`. Since I can't manage to get the `us` data I have just written what I suspect would work.

```
gm_y_corr %>% 
  group_by(iter_id) %>%  # group
  group_split() %>% # split
  lapply(., function(x){ # apply function(x) merge(us, x, by = "GEOID") to leach list element
    merge(us, x, by = "GEOID") 
  }) %>% 
  bind_rows() # collapse to data frame
```

equivalently this is the same as using base R functionality. The new `group_by %>% group_split` is a little more intuitive in my opinion.

```
gm_y_corr %>% 
  split(.$iter_id) %>% 
  lapply(., function(x){
    merge(us, x, by = "GEOID")
  }) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

If you wanted to just use `group_by` you would have to follow up with `dplyr::do` function which I believe does a similar thing to what I have just done above. But without you having to split it yourself.